# Gradient control by div and curl

Tags: vector-analysis

For any $u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^3)$ how to prove:

$$\|\nabla u\|_p \leq C(\|\operatorname{div}u\|_p+\|\operatorname{curl}u\|_p)$$

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What is $W^{1,p}(\Bbb R^3)$?

Comment: @Bye_World Sobolev space, maybe you can consider u is smooth with compact support first.